# How to estimate if a velocity field is statistically homogeneous?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, simulation, statistics

For a 3D velocity field $\mathbf{u}$ obtained by direct numerical simulation.

Assuming that the field is defined on a periodic domain $\mathcal{P}$ of periodicity $L_x$ in the $x$ direction,  $L_y$ in the $y$ direction and  $L_z$ in the $z$ direction.

Assuming that the simulation is computed from time $t_1$ to $t_2$.

How practically estimate the degree of statistical homogeneity of the velocity field?

Comment: Is a velocity field any different than other quantities? Can't you just compute mean velocity & standard derviation? Because $\mathbf u$ is vector-valued, you'd have a mean and a standard deviation for each component of the velocity vector individually. Also, you have time-dependent fields - so you can compute the suggested quantities for each time step or you can perform time averaging before you compute the mean and the standard deviation.

Comment: Maybe your should do an answer of your comment. I'm not sure if the velocity field is different or not of other quantities. Can it's been see like a tri-variate time series on each point of space?

Comment: I don't see why you should not be able to consider your fields as tri-variate time series. I think you still need to define whether "homogenous" in your case mean spatial or temporal homogeneity (or both).

As for an answer made out of the comment: I think a comment is fine, as I as a non-expert really consider my comment to be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I mean spatial homogeneity. I guess by temporal homogeneity you mean stationarity? ... statistically speaking.